# Domain user authentication in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, web-config, authorization, windows-authentication

I would like my asp .net web application to only allow users belonging to DomainName\Domain Users to access the site. Right now I have "Anonymous access" disabled and "Windows Integrated Security" enabled on IIS.  I also have the following code in my web config:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
    <allow roles="DomainName\Domain Users" />
    <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

When I attempt to access the website it prompts me for the username and password to connect to webserver.example.com. I am a member of the domain users group but it does not allow me access. What am I doing wrong either in the syntax or in my IIS settings?

Comment: try to enable impersonalization and btw is your iis server box part of the domain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is Anonymous Authentication Disabled in IIS ? Only Integrated Windows Auth should be enabled on the web application.

**EDIT from comments:**
I see you have Anonymous disabled. Try adding `<identity impersonate="true" />` within `<system.web>` and see if your behavior changes.

Comment: In other words anonymous access should be enabled? I need to track who is using the application (what is their domain name).

Comment: I'm trying to help you, I read a lot of questions, I missed it. I see you have Anonymous disabled. Try adding <identity impersonate="true" /> within <system.web> and see if your behavior changes.

Comment: There's no need to use impersonation. That changes what user the process runs as & has nothing to do with security

Comment: @Ross , if my answer didn't solve your problem, please unmark it as the answer... o_0

Comment: well, haha, thanks anyway, i did both things at the same time and it worked how i wanted. false assumption that both were needed i guess.

Comment: nah, it wasn't needed, edited solution above! u still get a checkmark because ur a cool cat.